Issue with accessing pages in Vue-Laravel (Vuexy) v9.10.0 - How to correctly display pages?
I’m working on a project using the Vue-Laravel template Vuexy v9.10.0, but I’m facing an issue with accessing the pages in my application. I can access the links to my pages according to the console, but all I see is a loader, no matter which link I access.
Here are a few details about my setup:
Vuexy version: v9.10.0

Vue version: Vue 3

Laravel version: 9.x

web.php file:
Route::get('{any?}', function() {
    return view('application');
})->where('any', '.*');

Vue Router:
    I’ve configured routes in resources/js/plugins/1.router/additional-routes.js.
    Using createRouter and createWebHistory in resources/js/plugins/index.js.
    The pages are defined in resources/js/views and should be rendered with RouterView in App.vue.

Could anyone help me figure out why my pages are not displaying correctly? I don’t see any errors in the console, and I suspect it might be related to either the router configuration or how views are being handled in Laravel.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Try update dependency
npm install
composer update

make sure Laravel route correctly setup
Route::get('{any?}', function() {
    return view('application');
})->where('any', '.*');

Make sure resources are setup correctly in application.blade.php
@vite(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.css'])

Check these steps and see if its working
